# Make embedded Soundcloud thumbnail printable with @media print

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries, soundcloud

When inserting an embedded Soundcloud player on a blog:

```html
 <iframe width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/271188615&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false&visual=true"></iframe>
```

it gives a nearly blank result when using the "Print" feature of the browser.

Question: is there a way (with `@media print`?) to make the printed result similar to what's displayed on the screen, i.e.:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no CSS on your domain will have effect on a page from other domain loaded on an iframe (it's for security reasons).

There are some [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) to inject CSS on an iframe using JS but the iframe's domain should have the appropriate [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) rule set and it doesn't seems to be the case.

If this is really important for you, you could always make a screenshot of the player and use for cover the actual player only for printing…

**Edit based on comments**

There's is not native attribute to do what you asked, but you could do it yourself with a little bit of JS + CSS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.soundcloud').forEach((iframe) => {
  var img_cover = iframe.getAttribute('cover');
  if (img_cover) {
    var org_html = iframe.outerHTML;
    var new_html = "<div class='soundcloud-iframe'>" +
      org_html +
      "<img src=" + img_cover + " width='500' height='300'>" +
      "</div>";
    iframe.outerHTML = new_html;
  }
});
```

```css
.soundcloud-iframe img {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .soundcloud-iframe iframe {
    display: none;
  }
  .soundcloud-iframe img {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe cover="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000169258529-6odvu9-t500x500.jpg" class="soundcloud" width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/271188615&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false&visual=true">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to make this automatically? Something like `<iframe ... alt-img-for-print="soundcloud.com/api/thumbnail/track/271188615">`? (this is pseudo code of course)